# Altium PCB Layout: Does each pcb footprint and trace segment have a unique identifier. Which stores information about at what time it was laid out?

Tags: altium, layout

Is there any information about when an element is placed on the PCB file in Altium?

A unique chronologically generated ID maybe?

Comment: There's probably an "undo" buffer that exsits during an editing session, but no permanent storage of that kind of information. Why would you need such a thing?

Comment: There's also a "History" folder where you can go back to a previous save/when a change was made.

Comment: Not for nets or footprints, the unique identifiers are for *instantiations* of a component.

Comment: I was going to do a timelapse of a PCB being made. Out of interest for our design flow.

However I have been recording my Altium sessions with screenshots so I have that as a fall back - its just not a constant alignment.